# 2 divs under an image to fill transparent color [html]

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, overlap

I have an image with transparent text, and I have one div that is a solid color that fills in that text, and allows the user to change the color. Now this works and all, but when it comes time to have another div cover another set of transparent text right under it, it gives issues. The two color divs just stack on each other, but I want the second div to be a little under the first div but still under the image.

Here is my code:

```
<tr><td colspan="3" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #eee;position:relative;">
        <img src="/sig/<?php echo $username; ?>?mask=1&bg=<?php echo $bg_name;?>" style="position: relative;width:240px;height:66px;z-index: 1;" id="selected_bg"/>
        <div style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 5px;width: 96%;height: 20px;background: #<?php echo $session_array['usrname_color']; ?>" id="usrname_color"></div>
        <div style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 5px;width: 96%;height: 20px;background: #<?php echo $session_array['text_color']; ?>" id="text_color"></div>

    </td></tr>
```

Comment: then you should give the different positions (top and left)

Comment: Both are `absolute` positioned divs having `top` as `0`

Comment: ok im aware of that, but im not sure what to change to make it work? someone modify it and make a jsfiddle maybe, so it works?

Comment: when i do "top: 1" on the second div, it moves itself to the bottom of the image and thats not my goal right now. i want it under

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I got it to work, but I added "px" after the second div, and it worked. Looks something like this:

```
<tr><td colspan="3" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #eee;position:relative;">
        <img src="/sig/<?php echo $username; ?>?mask=1&bg=<?php echo $bg_name;?>" style="position: relative;width:240px;height:66px;z-index: 1;" id="selected_bg"/>
        <div style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 5px;width: 96%;height: 20px;background: #<?php echo $session_array['usrname_color']; ?>" id="usrname_color"></div>
        <div style="position: absolute;top: 20px;left: 5px;width: 96%;height: 40px;background: #<?php echo $session_array['text_color']; ?>" id="text_color"></div>

    </td></tr>
```